# Implementation of a Trait over a Rc doesn't resolve to a Rc<dyn Trait>, following implementations were found <Rc<T> as Trait>

Tags: rust, traits, trait-objects

I'm trying to wrap a DST around a `Rc` with the aim of cloning it and accessing it from various parts of the code but the following error appears on compilation.

Here is a minimal reproducible example of the error ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=79485d464e6b777a30c9aa8a9960ddda)):

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Trait<'a> {
    fn return_hello(&self) -> &'a str;
}

impl<'a, F> Trait<'a> for F
where
    F: Fn() -> &'a str
{
    fn return_hello(&self) -> &'a str {
        self()
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Trait<'a> for Rc<T> 
where
    T: Trait<'a>
{
    fn return_hello(&self) -> &'a str {
        (**self).return_hello()
    } 
}

fn caller<'a, T>(t: T) 
where
    T: Trait<'a>
{
    print!("{}\n", t.return_hello());
}

fn main() {
    fn test1<'a>() -> &'a str {
        "Hello from function"
    }
    let test2 = move || "hello from closure";
    
    fn f<'a>() -> &'a str {
        "Hello from Rc"
    }
    let test3: Rc<dyn Trait<'_>> = Rc::new(f);

    caller(test1);
    caller(test2);
    caller(test3);
}
```

Gives:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Rc<dyn Trait<'_>>: Trait<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:45:12
   |
25 | fn caller<'a, T>(t: T) 
   |    ------ required by a bound in this
26 | where
27 |     T: Trait<'a>
   |        --------- required by this bound in `caller`
...
45 |     caller(test3);
   |            ^^^^^ the trait `Trait<'_>` is not implemented for `Rc<dyn Trait<'_>>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <Rc<T> as Trait<'a>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `impl for Rc<T>` has an implicit requirement that `T: Sized`, as if you wrote:

```
impl<'a, T> Trait<'a> for Rc<T> 
where
    T: Trait<'a> + Sized //The latter is implicit
```

But when you want to apply it to a `Rc<dyn Trait<'a>>` then the type `T` is `dyn Trait<'a>`, that is not `Sized`, so it does not apply.

The solution is to add `+ ?Sized` to relax that requirement [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1775e1c08640b3f1912f1abd6ed8e102):

```
impl<'a, T> Trait<'a> for Rc<T> 
where
    T: Trait<'a> + ?Sized
```

And now that you are into it you can add it to the other `impl` too:

```
impl<'a, F> Trait<'a> for F
where
    F: Fn() -> &'a str + ?Sized
```

so that it applies to `dyn Fn() -> &'a str`, too.

Comment: Cleaner way ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cd5311a7869017521b67920fe7d7f9d2)):
`impl<'a> Trait<'a> for Rc<dyn Trait<'a>> { ... }`

Comment: @dvec But that's constrained to DSTs only, I want it to allow the `Rc` to hold `Sized` and `?Sized` types, but thanks for the help.

Comment: @dvec: But that `impl` only applies to that particular type, not to any other `Rc<T>` where `T: Trait<'a>`  but it is different from `dyn Trait<'a>`. For example `struct S {}; impl<'a> Trait<'a> for S { ... }`. Does `Rc<S>` implement `Trait<'a>`?

Answer (score 1):

In the implementation of `Rc<T>` for `Trait`, `T` have an implicit bound of `Sized` ([source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/marker/trait.Sized.html)) because of that, the implementations of `Rc<T>` will only resolve to `Sized` types. Simply telling that `T` "may not be sized" will solve the problem, so add a `?Sized`.

```rust
impl<'a, T> Trait<'a> for Rc<T> 
where
    T: ?Sized + Trait<'a>
{
    fn return_hello(&self) -> &'a str {
        (**self).return_hello()
    } 
}
```